# Building docker image causing "stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory" on CentOS while working on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which works (build and run) on Ubuntu 18.04. Now, I have to build it on a CentOS 7 machine where I have very limited rights.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update

ENTRYPOINT echo "Hello world"
```

When I try to build via `docker build -t foo .` (while being in the directory with the Dockerfile) I'll get

> Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
>
> Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
>
> ---> 20bb25d32758
>
> Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update
>
> ---> Running in dcb3efe30efb
>
> container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"
>
> oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process
>   caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"

See also screenshot
[image]

All I find on Google is about `Entrypoint` etc, but my problem is obviously there before I even get to the Entrypoint.

On the CentOS 7 host, there is definitely /bin/sh. I can execute a Shell script foo.sh by running the command `/bin/sh foo.sh` without any trouble.

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem. `docker build` or `docker run`?. It looks like you are mixing logs.

Comment: My problem is `docker build`.

Comment: can you please attach the full output after running build along with the build command?

Comment: @dongi Added command and complete output in my question.

Comment: Can you check that `/bin/sh` is available in your `ubuntu:18.04` image by running `docker run --rm ubuntu:18.04 ls -l /bin/sh`? If `/bin/sh` does not exist, your base image (`ubuntu:18.04`) may be corrupted.

Comment: Please include the output of `docker image inspect ubuntu:18.04` and `docker system info`

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here after messing around multiple hours with the same issue:

The issue in my case was with a corrupt image. It was very stubborn to disappear :)

So try with `docker system prune -a`, restart docker and build again.

**Note** that this removes all your images and containers, which can not be undone.
For more see: [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Ran into the same weird thing, and only when trying to use Buildkit. the system prune worked